# Does OpenMP supports work stealing mechanism?

Tags: gcc, openmp

I am working with sources of `gcc-4.7.4` compiler. I must to learn work of `OpenMP` libraries and I have read documentations of different versions of OpenMP and I didn't find any information about wok stealing mechanism. Is that true, that OpenMP does not support work stealing mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenMP takes almost all of the responsibility for work scheduling out of the hands of the programmer.  There is no explicit support for work-stealing, nor any other scheduling policy save for specifying how loop iterations are to be divided across processors.

However, an OpenMP implementation may choose to use work-stealing.  The approach would be entirely suitable for the explicit `task` construct that OpenMP supports.  Equally, an implementation may choose another scheduling approach.

I have read that the gcc implementation does use work-stealing, but it's not something I've looked into and I may be wrong.

Comment: I must admit I had never heard of [work stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) until now. It would be nice to describe what it is and how it contrasts to work sharing.

Comment: Work stealing sounds vaguely like the stack based method I used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675466/reductions-in-parallel-in-logarithmic-time).

Comment: @Zboson: well, the Wikipedia article you link to provides the nice descriptions you seek.