# private variables vs reduction in OMP

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

I am trying to understand how OMP treats different `for` loop declarations. I have:

```
int main()
{
   int i, A[10000]={...};
   double ave = 0.0;
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ave)
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
       ave += A[i];
   }

   ave /= 10000;

   printf("Average value = %0.4f\n",ave);
   return 0;
}
```

where `{...}` are the numbers form 1 to 10000. This code prints the correct value. If instead of `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ave)` I use `#pragma omp parallel for private(ave)` the result of the `printf` is `0.0000`. I think I understand what `reduction(oper:list)` does, but was wondering if it can be substituted for `private` and how.

Comment: Short answer: No you can't. Longer one: well you could do something of this kind, but why would you want to do that? (hint: this is likely to be a bad idea)

Comment: @Gilles The point is I saw it in someone else's code. That code produces the correct result, so it made me think. Moreover why is it printing 0?

Comment: So what do you expect as answer? An example of your code printing the right value without using the `reduction` clause?

Comment: @Gilles More specifically one using private if possible. Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to do a reduction by hand https://stackoverflow.com/q/35675466/2542702. I think it's a very useful exercise to go through for educational purposes. Especially in cases where operations don't commute which the `reduction` clause does not support.

Comment: @Zboson Looks like a useful read. I will go through it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So yes, you can do reductions without the `reduction` clause. But that has a few downsides that you have to understand:

1. You have to do things by hand, which is more error-prone:

   - declare local variables to store local accumulations;
   - initialize them correctly;
   - accumulate into them;
   - do the final reduction in the initial variable using a `critical` construct.
2. This is harder to understand and maintain
3. This is potentially less effective...

Anyway, here is an example of that using your code:

```
int main() {
   int i, A[10000]={...};
   double ave = 0.0;
   double localAve;

   #pragma omp parallel private( i, localAve )
   {
       localAve = 0;
       #pragma omp for
       for( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
           localAve += A[i];
       }
       #pragma omp critical
       ave += localAve;
   }

   ave /= 10000;

   printf("Average value = %0.4f\n",ave);
   return 0;
}
```

This is a classical method for doing reductions by hand, but notice that the variable that would have been declared `reduction` isn't declared `private` here. What becomes `private` is a local substitute of this variable while the global one must remain `shared`.

Comment: Among the problems solved for you by reduction clause is the question of efficient accumulation of individual thread sums (for example, by a tree method to get a little parallelism).

Comment: That makes sense. I will go through the original code (the one mentioned in previous comments) again to try and find what exactly is going on. It uses #pragma omp parallel for private... and no critical. I understand the principle of operation for each construct separately, just need to piece them together.