# Why should I use a reduction rather than an atomic variable?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, atomic

Assume we want to count something in an OpenMP loop. Compare the reduction

```
int counter = 0;
#pragma omp for reduction( + : counter )
for (...) {
    ...
    counter++;
}
```

with the atomic increment

```
int counter = 0;
#pragma omp for
for (...) {
    ...
    #pragma omp atomic
    counter++
}
```

The atomic access provides the result immediately, while a reduction only assumes its correct value at the end of the loop. For instance, reductions do not allow this:

```
int t = counter;
if (t % 1000 == 0) {
    printf ("%dk iterations\n", t/1000);
}
```

thus providing less functionality.

Why would I ever use a reduction instead of atomic access to a counter?

Comment: Whenever you write to an atomic variable, there's a syncronization point where other threads might need to wait. With reduction it's not needed until the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer:

**Performance**

### Long Answer:

Because an atomic variable comes with a price, and this price is synchronization.
In order to ensure that there is no race conditions i.e. two threads modifying the same variable at the same moment, threads must **synchronize** which effectively means that you lose parallelism, i.e. threads are **serialized**.

Reduction on the other hand is a general operation that can be carried out **in parallel** using parallel reduction algorithms.
Read [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675466/reductions-in-parallel-in-logarithmic-time) articles for more info about parallel reduction algorithms.

---

#### Addendum: Getting a sense of how a parallel reduction work

Imagine a scenario where you have `4` threads and you want to reduce a `8` element array A. What you could do this in 3 steps (check the attached image to get a better sense of what I am talking about):

- **Step 0**. Threads with index `i<4` take care of the result of summing `A[i]=A[i]+A[i+4]`.
- **Step 1**. Threads with index `i<2` take care of the result of summing `A[i]=A[i]+A[i+4/2]`.
- **Step 2**. Threads with index `i<4/4` take care of the result of summing `A[i]=A[i]+A[i+4/4]`

At the end of this process you will have the result of your reduction in the first element of `A` i.e. `A[0]`

[image]

Comment: Your explanation of how a parallel reduction works is not realistic based on OpenMP implementations. At least not on CPUS. They simply do one partial sum/reduction and for each thread and then they add up /reduce each partial result linearly. For `N>>nthreads` this works file. Doing the reduction in `log(nthreads)` is nice in theory but not in practice. You could show the OP how to the reduction manually do understand this.

Comment: @Zboson Of course it is not realistic of the actual implementation, but at least gives OP an idea of why this is better than using atomic. The goal of my answer is far from being a reference on how scan operations are implemented in OpenMP. I have updated the answer also with the link you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Performance is the key point.

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define N 1000000
int a[N], sum;

int main(){
  double begin, end;

  begin=omp_get_wtime();
  for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
    sum+=a[i];
  end=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("serial %g\t",end-begin);

  begin=omp_get_wtime();
# pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
# pragma omp atomic
    sum+=a[i];
  end=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("atomic %g\t",end-begin);

  begin=omp_get_wtime();
# pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
    sum+=a[i];
  end=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("reduction %g\n",end-begin);
}
```

When executed (gcc -O3 -fopenmp), it gives :

serial 0.00491182   atomic 0.0786559    reduction 0.001103

So approximately atomic=20xserial=80xreduction

The 'reduction' exploits properly the parallelism, and with a 4 cores computer, we can get 3--6 performances boosts vs "serial".

Now, "atomic" is 20 times longer than "serial". Not only, as explained in the previous answer, the serialization of memory accesses disables parallelism, but all memory accesses are done by atomic operations. These operations require at least 20--50 cycles on modern computers and will dramatically slow down your performances if used intensively.