# Why my parallel code using openMP atomic takes a longer time than serial code?

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

The snippet of my serial code is shown below.

```
 Program main
  use omp_lib
  Implicit None
   
  Integer :: i, my_id
  Real(8) :: t0, t1, t2, t3, a = 0.0d0

  !$ t0 = omp_get_wtime()
  Call CPU_time(t2)
  ! ------------------------------------------ !

    Do i = 1, 100000000
      a = a + Real(i)
    End Do

  ! ------------------------------------------ !
  Call CPU_time(t3)
  !$ t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  ! ------------------------------------------ !

  Write (*,*) "a = ", a
  Write (*,*) "The wall time is ", t1-t0, "s"
  Write (*,*) "The CPU time is ", t3-t2, "s"
End Program main
```

The elapsed time:
[image]

By using omp directives `do` and `atomic`, I convert serial code into parallel code. However, the parallel program is slower than the serial program. I don't understand why this happened. The next is my parallel code snippet:

```
Program main
  use omp_lib
  Implicit None
    
  Integer, Parameter :: n_threads = 8
  Integer :: i, my_id
  Real(8) :: t0, t1, t2, t3, a = 0.0d0
 
  !$ t0 = omp_get_wtime()
  Call CPU_time(t2)
  ! ------------------------------------------ !

  !$OMP Parallel Num_threads(n_threads) shared(a)
  
   !$OMP Do 
     Do i = 1, 100000000
       !$OMP Atomic
       a = a + Real(i)
     End Do
   !$OMP End Do
  
  !$OMP End Parallel
  
  ! ------------------------------------------ !
  Call CPU_time(t3)
  !$ t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  ! ------------------------------------------ !

  Write (*,*) "a = ", a
  Write (*,*) "The wall time is ", t1-t0, "s"
  Write (*,*) "The CPU time is ", t3-t2, "s"
End Program main
```

The elapsed time: [image]

So **my question** is Why my parallel code using openMP atomic takes a longer time than serial code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying an `atomic` operation to the same variable in every single loop iteration. Moreover, that variable has interdependencies among those loop iterations. Naturally, that comes with additional overheads (*e.g.,* synchronization, cost of serialization, and CPU cycles) when comparing with the sequential version. Furthermore, you are probably getting a lot of cache misses due to threads invalidating their caches.

This code is the typical code that should be using a `reduction` of the variable `a` (*i.e.,* `!$omp parallel do reduction(+:a))` instead of an atomic operation. With the reduction operation, each thread will have a private copy of the variable `'a'`, and at end of the `parallel region`, threads will reduce their copies of the variable `'a'` (using the `'+'` operator) into a single value that will be propagated to the variable `'a'` of the main thread.

You can find a more detailed answer about the differences between atomic *vs.* reduction on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186268/why-should-i-use-a-reduction-rather-than-an-atomic-variable). In that thread, there is even a code, which (just like yours) its `atomic` version is several orders of magnitude slower than its sequential counterpart (*i.e.,* 20x slower). In that case it is even worst than yours (*i.e., 20x Vs 10x*).