# Simplest example of parallel run using OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Consider the following code construct,

```
int n = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       n++;
```

Now the above is the simplest possible demo of a similar thing I am trying to implement in a code that takes a large amount of time. So, the main objective is to parallelize the loops such that the runtime reduces.

I am new to OpenMP, just know some commands and that's all. Now in the code I have written above, the final result comes wrong (n = 9 is the right answer). I guess, the loops are trying to access the same memory location simultaneuouly.

Now can someone give a simplest possible solution to this. Please note that I very much a noob regarding this. And any reading material regarding this will also be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess, the loops are trying to access the same memory location
> simultaneuouly.

**TL,DR :** Yes, you have a *race-condition* during the updates of the variable `n`. One way of solving that is using the OpenMP reduction clause.

> I am new to OpenMP, just know some commands and that's all. Now in the
> code I have written above, the final result comes wrong (n = 9 is the
> right answer).

**The longer answer:**

The `#pragma omp parallel for` will create a `parallel region`, and to the `threads` of that region the iterations of the loop that it encloses will be assigned, using the `default chunk size`, and the `default schedule` which is *typically* `static`. Bear in mind, however, that the `default schedule` might differ among different concrete implementation of the `OpenMP` standard.

From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) you can read a more formal description :

> The worksharing-loop construct specifies that the iterations of one or
> more associated loops will be executed in parallel by threads in the
> team in the context of their implicit tasks. **The iterations are
> distributed across threads that already exist in the team that is
> executing the parallel region to which the worksharing-loop region
> binds**.

[Moreover](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf),

> The parallel loop construct is a shortcut for specifying a parallel
> construct containing a loop construct with one or more associated
> loops and no other statements.

Or informally, `#pragma omp parallel for` is a combination of the constructor `#pragma omp parallel` with `#pragma omp for`.

Therefore, what is happening in your code is that you have multiple threads modifying concurrently the value of `n`, to solve this problem you should use OpenMP reduction clause, which from the OpenMP standard one can read:

> **The reduction clause can be used to perform some forms of recurrence
> calculations (...) in parallel.** For parallel and work-sharing
> constructs, a private copy of each list item is created, one for each
> implicit task, as if the private clause had been used. (...) The
> private copy is then initialized as specified above. At the end of the
> region for which the reduction clause was specified, the original list
> item is updated by combining its original value with the final value
> of each of the private copies, using the combiner of the specified
> reduction-identifier.

For a more detailed explanation on how the *reduction* clause works have a look a this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406478/how-does-openmp-use-the-atomic-instruction-inside-reduction-clause/65406679#65406679).

So to solve the *race-condition* in your code just changed it to:

```
 int n = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) reduction(+:n)
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        n++;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!