# OpenMP returning wrong result

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

The code below should use 4 threads to calculate the summation of all numbers between 0 and 1000. It should return 499500 but it is returning different values at each execution.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int nthreads, i, tid;
        float total;

        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) 
        {
            tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            if (tid == 0) {
                nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                cout << "Número de threads = " << nthreads <<endl;
            }
           #pragma omp barrier

           total = 0.0;
           #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,10) private(i)
           for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
               total = total + i*1.0;
        } 
        cout << "Total = " <<total << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening in your code is that you have multiple threads concurrently modifying the value of the variable `total`. To solve this issue, you can use OpenMP `reduction` clause, which from the [OpenMP standard](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) one can read:

> **The reduction clause can be used to perform some forms of recurrence
> calculations (...) in parallel.** For parallel and work-sharing
> constructs, a private copy of each list item is created, one for each
> implicit task, as if the private clause had been used. (...) The
> private copy is then initialized as specified above. At the end of the
> region for which the reduction clause was specified, the original list
> item is updated by combining its original value with the final value
> of each of the private copies, using the combiner of the specified
> reduction-identifier.

For a more detailed explanation on how the *reduction* clause works have a look a this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406478/how-does-openmp-use-the-atomic-instruction-inside-reduction-clause/65406679#65406679).

So to solve the *race-condition* in your code just changed it to:

```
        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,10) private(i) reduction(+:total)
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
             total = total + i*1.0;
```

After applying the reduction clause, to avoid wrong results, do not initialize the shared variable `total` within the parallel region:

```
total = 0.0;
```

simply set it before the parallel region.

There is another *race condition* regarding the variable *tid* itself, which is shared among threads and updated concurrently inside the parallel region:

```
tid = omp_get_thread_num();
```

This can be solve by making `tid` private to each thread for instance:

```
int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
```

**Side Notes**

In OpenMP the outermost loop enclosed by the `#pragma omp for` will have its index variable (`i` in this context) already private, therefore the clause `private(i)` is not really necessary.

Another point is the `schedule(dynamic,10)`; unless you are just *playing around*, it actually makes more sense (performance-wise) to use the schedule `static`, since the code does not lead to loading balancing issues. The `dynamic` schedule has the additional overhead of *assigning* at run-time the tasks to threads, whereas the assignment in the `static` schedule is performed at compile-time.

Finally, the following :

```
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    if (tid == 0) {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        cout << "Número de threads = " << nthreads <<endl;
    }
```

can be simplified by using the [OpenMP master clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-directives?view=msvc-160#master), namely:

```
    #pragma omp master
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        cout << "Número de threads = " << nthreads <<endl;
    }
```

A running solution with the changes applied:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        float total = 0.0;

        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) 
        {
           #pragma omp master
           {
                int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                cout << "Número de threads = " << nthreads <<endl;
           }
           #pragma omp barrier

           #pragma omp for reduction(+:total)
           for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
               total = total + i*1.0;
        } 
        cout << "Total = " <<total << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Número de threads = 4
Total = 499500
```